# Force PouchDB to use http/2

Tags: reactjs, http, couchdb, http2, pouchdb

I am using pouchdb-browser in the context of a React-App to connect to a CouchDB Server. I have a growing application and now I have the problem that the limit of 6 (or whatever) concurrent connections to a host when using Http1.1 is getting a problem.

As a workaround I am setting the network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server=100 on Firefox, so I don't have to bother -- but for deployment: Is it possible to force PouchDB to use http/2 for the connection to the CouchDB-Server?`

Best Regards,
Tobias

Comment: Not sure if this is directly related to your problem but apparently CouchDB does itself not yet support HTTP/2 (see this open issue https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1497)

Comment: I was having the same question. Even if CouchDB itself doesn't support HTTP/2, you could run it behind a reverse proxy that terminates HTTP/2 and benefit from the potential speedup when running many consecutive requests. So would be helpful if PouchDB had support for that. Is there a way to instruct the PouchDB client to simply utilize the browser's fetch API or so?